# How to assign rights to everybody in django?

Tags: python, django

I use django to develop my web application. I am able to use the rights management system and understand it. I can assign rights to users and groups and assign users to groups.

My simple question is: how to implement an "everybody"-group I may assign several rights? Or is there an other way? I checked SE and django docs but did not found any solution or explanations about my case.

Comment: If you want to give every user rights to every model, then could make everyone a superuser.
Or you could create a group, `everyone`, add permissions for models you want to give permissions to everyone, and add that group to every user

Comment: If everybody is going to have those rights, then why do you need the rights at all? Just take that functionality out of any permissions and everybody will be able to do it.

Comment: @elssar: how to ensure every user is in every time in this group?

Comment: @StuartLeigh jep, but I run multiple instances of my application and some need a right for everybody and some do not.